# Table.* notation does not work in a 'group by' query

Tags: sql, oracle

On an oracle database, the `Table.*` notation does not work inside a 'select..group by..' query.

This query with no * works :

```
select A.id from TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B on A.id=B.aid group by A.id
```

This one with a * does not :

```
select A.*  from TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B on A.id=B.aid group by A.id
```

The output is

```
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

Why does this query not work? Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Unlike MySQL, most database systems will reject this - they don't know what values to select for the *other* columns not included in `GROUP BY` - should they `SUM()` them? Take the `AVG()`? Give the `MIN()` or `MAX()`? etc. Bear in mind that tables are unordered so I've not included "first" or "last" on that list since that requires even more information adding to the question and to the query.

Comment: This is normal behavior, where did you learn that this would work?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I think it's **all** database systems except MySQL (not "most")

Comment: And you should not be using select * in any event, it is very poor programming practice.

Comment: If you post some sample data and expected results we can help you write the query you need. It is unusaul to group on the id column alone (since it will probably be the PK and thus unique. So I am not sure that grouping is what you want anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - any time I post an assured statement "Only MySQL ...", someone seems to turn up with a counterexample to prove me wrong. I'm tending to hedge these days :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround.
Assuming that each id in A is unique, then you don't even need to use group by, just:

```
select * from A
where id in (
   select id from b
);
```

If id are not unique in A table, then you can simulate MySql functionality with this query:

```
select * from A
where rowid in (
  select min( a.rowid ) 
  from a
  join b on a.id = b.id
  group by a.id
);
```

Here is a link to [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fb1f/1)
Here is a link to MySql documentation where their extension to group by is explained: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html
Pay attention to this fragment:

> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful
>   primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in
>   the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose
>   any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values
>   chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from
>   each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting
>   of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY
>   does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

Answer (score 8):

Everything you selecting except agregate functions (`MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, COUNT...`) must be in `Group by`

Comment: Is there a workaround to rewrite the query without the column names? I would like the query to stay the same when I add new columns to the table.

Comment: +1 @slavoo, but there are a few exceptions: constant values, `SYSDATE`, grouping functions such as `GROUP_ID` and `GROUPING`, plus a few more I'm sure I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 3):

A group by expression must include all the columns you select. So, if the table has 3 columns (column1, column2 and column3), you have to group by all of them like this: group by Column1, Column2, Column3. The * means you select all the columns, so add all of them in the group by expression.